# JS Compare two objects and return new key saying who has the highest value

Tags: javascript

I have one array of objects:

```
teamScores: [
    { teamName: 'Team name 1', points: 21},
    { teamName: 'Team name 2', points: 11},
  ],
```

I need to compare the key 'points' within these two objects and return a new key saying if its the highest value. For this example the return should be:

```
teamScores: [
    { teamName: 'Team name 1', points: 21, isHighest: true},
    { teamName: 'Team name 2', points: 11, isHighest: false},
  ],
```

And vice versa:

```
teamScores: [
    { teamName: 'Team name 1', points: 11, isHighest: false},
    { teamName: 'Team name 2', points: 21, isHighest: true},
  ],
```

I tried to use .reduce() but it didn't work so well. Here is my try:

```
const newTeams = scoreTeams.reduce((acc, team, idx) => {
  const isHigh = scoreTeams[idx].points > scoreTeams[idx - 1]?.points;
  const accTeam = {
    ...team,
    isHighest: isHigh,
  };
  acc[idx] = accTeam;
  return acc;
}, []);
```

If the first object has a lower value it works well, the output:

```
teamScores: [
    { teamName: 'Team name 1', points: 11, isHighest: false},
    { teamName: 'Team name 2', points: 21, isHighest: true},
  ],
```

But if the first value is higher than the second, it doesn't work so well, the output:

```
teamScores: [
    { teamName: 'Team name 1', points: 21, isHighest: false},
    { teamName: 'Team name 2', points: 11, isHighest: false},
  ],
```

I need help to compare these objects properly, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over each object to get an array of the all the points.
2. Find the highest value of that array. ([`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) finds the highest value from a list of values. Because we're passing it an array we have to [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the values out).
3. Return a new array of updated objects where `isHighest` is set to `true` or `false` if the object's `points` value matches the `highest` value.

```js
const scores = [
  { teamName: 'Team name 1', points: 21 },
  { teamName: 'Team name 2', points: 11 }
];

// Collate the points
const points = scores.map(obj => obj.points);

// Find the highest point
const highest = Math.max(...points);

// `spread` out the initial object into a new object
// and add the new `isHighest` value
const out = scores.map(obj => {
  return { ...obj, isHighest: obj.points === highest };
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Man that worked really well, I'm gonna try working destructuring steps from now as you did, thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, @ViníciusCardoso, If you break down your steps it becomes 1) easier to test 2) If you have to work in a team it makes the code easier to understand for them if they have to do code reviews.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need two iterations. One to identify the highest, and one to set the property in each object.

```js
const teamScores = [
    { teamName: 'Team name 1', points: 21},
    { teamName: 'Team name 2', points: 11},
];

const maxPoints = Math.max(...teamScores.map(({points}) => points));
const newTeams = teamScores.map(o => ({...o, isHighest: o.points === maxPoints}));

console.log(newTeams);
```

Answer (score 1):

First find the highest with `Math.max`, then compare `points` of every elements with the max.

```
var teamScores = [
  { teamName: "Team name 1", points: 21 },
  { teamName: "Team name 2", points: 11 },
];
const max = Math.max(...teamScores.map((x) => x.points));
teamScores = teamScores.map((x) => ({...x, isHighest: x.points === max}));
console.log(teamScores);
```